# Remember add to cart form state

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to remember the chosen product attribute on the add to cart form? I have a product with a couple of options. If the users selects one on the product page and goes to another page, the form will reset and selects the first option again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in session

During Add to cart.

```
$_SESSION['my_module_name']['product_id']['field_name'] = $filter_value
```

Then set form option value from session

```
function my_module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    $get_default_value = isset($_SESSION['my_module_name']['product_id']['field_name'])?$_SESSION['my_module_name']['product_id']['field_name']:'';
    $form['field_name']['#default_value'] = $get_default_value;
  }
}
```